# Solving two systems with two unknown?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, problem-solving

Let's say if we are giving the following two equations:

$$ 1= X/(X^2 +Y^2) $$
$$ 2= Y/(X^2 +Y^2) $$

How are we going to solve for X and Y [ by HAND ] ?

Why would Summing the squares of the two equations would be one of the approach to solve for X and Y?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ and $Y$ are not both equal to zero, you can divide one by another. Let's say $X\neq 0$. Then, dividing the second by the first you obtain $Y=2X$. Now plug this into one of the equations.

Comment: Note that $X=0$ and $Y\neq 0$ (or vice-versa) is not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
5
= 1^2+2^2
= \frac{X^2}{(X^2+Y^2)^2}+\frac{Y^2}{(X^2+Y^2)^2}
=\frac{X^2+Y^2}{(X^2+Y^2)^2}
= \frac{1}{X^2+Y^2}
$$
so $X^2+Y^2=1/5$. The original equations then give $X=1/5$ and $Y=2/5$.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer. Maybe I should clarify my question-  
I just wonder why, or under what rule, allow you to just sum and add the two equations to get the solution?  Thanks in advance!